# try to make meme generate apps in android but see below error

Tags: android, mobile, imageview

[image]

It is Java Problem or something I need to change? when I deleted this line `ImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));`
after Apps runs but upload image does not work. All functions are working but not uploading image.

Comment: Can you post full activity code. So that i can tell you way to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to set image to `ImageView` *class* instead of `ImageView` *instance*

Your code should looks like this:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.myImageViewName);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
```

Of course your `ImageView` should exist in your `MainActivity` layout.

btw copy your code to description of your post and learn about static methods

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply an image to the ImageView class directly without having specified ImageView by its ID.

First, call the ImageView variable, cast it by ID, then you can apply the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)` to it like this;

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
```